# Deleting from local storage using javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I am using data attributes to store information about products on my website. Once these are added to the shopping basket, i would like to allow the user to delete any item if they wish.

The way I am storing the items in localstorage is as a json javascript object with the key "basket".
If i log to the console the basket after i have added two iMacs and one MacBook Pro this is what the output is.

```
"basket: {"iMac":{"ID":"2","Name":"iMac","Description":"2011 model 27 inch screen","stockQuantity":"15","Price":"1199.99","basketQuantity":2},"MacBook Pro Retina":{"ID":"7","Name":"MacBook Pro Retina","Description":"2015 MacBook Pro Retina display","stockQuantity":"30","Price":"999","basketQuantity":1}}"
```

The way i have been trying to overcome this problem is by adding a data attribute to the remove button `data-name="iMac"` for example. After this once the button is clicked, use `localStorage.removeItem(key)` to delete the selected item.

I have found this problematic because when using `localStorage.removeItem(key)` i have to use the key `"basket"` and can't access the object further from here.

What i am asking for is if there is a way to access the object by using the key `"basket"`.

I am adding an event listener to each of the remove buttons on the page using this function

```
function setDeleteButtons(){
  removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".removeItem");
  var basketStorage = localStorage.getItem("basket");
  jsonBasket = JSON.parse(basketStorage);

  for(i=0; i<removeButtons.length; i++){
      removeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        delete jsonBasket[e.currentTarget.dataset.name];
      });
      localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(jsonBasket));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read stored object and remove item by its `key` from inner `basket` object:

```
// Read and parse entire stored object
var basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));

// Delete specific item from the basket, key might be "iMac", etc.
delete basket[key];

// Save new basket
localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
```

**UPD.** The real problem lays in the remove function. You need to set new localStorage object after every button click:

```
removeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    delete jsonBasket[e.currentTarget.dataset.name];
    localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(jsonBasket));
});
```

Comment: when i tried this, i got an error in the console saying `obj.basket is undefined`

Comment: What is the strucuture of the localStorage object you save?

Comment: I gave an example in my question

Comment: but if i check localstorage in the inspector it shows this `{"iMac":{"ID":"2","Name":"iMac","Description":"2011 model 27 inch screen","stockQuantity":"15","Price":"1199.99","basketQuantity":2},"MacBook Pro Retina":{"ID":"7","Name":"MacBook Pro Retina","Description":"2015 MacBook Pro Retina display","stockQuantity":"30","Price":"999","basketQuantity":1}}`

Comment: You didn't use `your-key` literally, did you? I gave this just as an example, because you didn't mention in the question under what key you store entire object in local storage.

Comment: Check updated answer, I think you store it as a `basket` key. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No i didn't use that, i think my problem lies with a loop in which i am adding an event listener, i will update the question to see if you can find a problem there